# Why my_task.delay() works only within tasks module, not in models or views modules?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have created tasks.py in my app. Celery tasks I have created can be called in cmd or inside tasks.py itself. But it is not possible to call them in views.py or models.py.

Comment: Why not? What happens when you try? Show some code age the errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

**Where you file at? it should be inside your django project to be use.**

If you place it in some folder keep in mind to make one file `__init__.py` so django can see that folder as part of the project

```
project
- app1
- - __init__.py
- - models.py
- - admin.py
- - ...
- app2
- - __init__.py
- - models.py
- - admin.py
- - ...
- tasks
- - __init__.py
- - my_task_file.py
```

Or you can use as command line:

```
import os

os.system('<code to call your script>');
```